# Error 85 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo' to 'Mono.Cecil.TypeReference'

Tags: static, analysis, gendarme

Presently I am attempting to build Gendarme 2.10 using Visual Studio 2010.  Here are some of the errors I'm receiving:

```
Error   85  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo' to 'Mono.Cecil.TypeReference'   C:\Tools\mono-tools\external\cecil\Test\Mono.Cecil.Tests\CustomAttributesTests.cs   359 45  Mono.Cecil.Tests
Error   12  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Reflection.FieldInfo' to 'Mono.Cecil.TypeReference' C:\Tools\mono-tools\external\cecil\Test\Mono.Cecil.Tests\ImportReflectionTests.cs   103 45  Mono.Cecil.Tests
Error   24  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Reflection.FieldInfo' to 'Mono.Cecil.TypeReference' C:\Tools\mono-tools\external\cecil\Test\Mono.Cecil.Tests\ImportReflectionTests.cs   149 44  Mono.Cecil.Tests
Error   46  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Reflection.FieldInfo' to 'Mono.Cecil.TypeReference' C:\Tools\mono-tools\external\cecil\Test\Mono.Cecil.Tests\ImportReflectionTests.cs   198 44  Mono.Cecil.Tests
Error   60  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Reflection.FieldInfo' to 'Mono.Cecil.TypeReference' C:\Tools\mono-tools\external\cecil\Test\Mono.Cecil.Tests\ImportReflectionTests.cs   276 39      Mono.Cecil.Tests
Error   14  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo' to 'Mono.Cecil.TypeReference'    C:\Tools\mono-tools\external\cecil\Test\Mono.Cecil.Tests\ImportReflectionTests.cs   117 43  Mono.Cecil.Tests
```

After I remove all the tests projects, here are the errors I'm getting:

```
Error   4   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'Mono.Cecil.TypeReference' C:\Tools\mono-tools\gendarme\framework\Gendarme.Framework.Helpers\PrimitiveReferences.cs    53  25  Gendarme.Framework
Error   3   The best overloaded method match for 'Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Import(Mono.Cecil.TypeReference)' has some invalid arguments  C:\Tools\mono-tools\gendarme\framework\Gendarme.Framework.Helpers\PrimitiveReferences.cs    53  10  Gendarme.Framework
```

Here is the code that the above two errors refer to:

```
static TypeReference GetReference (Type type, IMetadataTokenProvider metadata)
{
    ModuleDefinition module = metadata.GetAssembly ().MainModule;
    TypeReference tr;
    if (!module.TryGetTypeReference (type.FullName, out tr))
        tr = module.Import (type);
    return tr;
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

Roger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a temporary solution I put together.  Please feel free to comment:

```
    static TypeReference GetReference (Type type, IMetadataTokenProvider metadata)
    {
        ModuleDefinition module = metadata.GetAssembly ().MainModule;
        ModuleKind kind = ModuleKind.Windows;
        ModuleDefinition definition = ModuleDefinition.CreateModule(module.Name, kind);
        Version version = new Version(1, 0);
        AssemblyNameDefinition nameDefinition = new AssemblyNameDefinition(module.Name, version);
        AssemblyDefinition assemblyDefinition = AssemblyDefinition.CreateAssembly(nameDefinition, definition.Name, kind);
        assemblyDefinition = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(module.Name);
        definition.Assembly = assemblyDefinition;
        IMetadataScope scope = new ModuleReference(module.Name);
        scope.MetadataToken = assemblyDefinition.MetadataToken;

        TypeReference tr = new TypeReference(type.Namespace, type.Name, definition, scope);
        //if (!module.TryGetTypeReference(type.FullName, out tr))
        //    tr = module.Import(type);
        return tr;
    }
```